# Video format or MIME type is not supported in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, html5-video

Upload video using paperclip-ffmpeg.
It save fine.But when I show it on browser it shown but not play.It gvies error on video

```
Video format or MIME type is not supported
```

Showing video like this

```
<%= video_tag @ad.videod.url(:medium), controls: true, type: "video/flv", size: "640x480" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML `<video>` tag (and thus the Rails `video_tag`) does not support `video/flv` format. You need to use some Flash-based player to play it. Or, better, transcode the video to `MP4` or `OGG` format.

Comment: Not only with flv .In every video this happen

Comment: Try to remove the `type` attribute at all, and ensure that your video is actually in some format that be played by your browser (typically the MP4).